# MailApp.sendEmail does not send emails outside of workspace

Tags: google-apps-script

Emails sent from the script do not reach the recipient if it is outside the workspace. However, they are in the sent. Perhaps you need to specify some special IP in the SPF-record?

I do not get Delivery Status Failure email. I also tried email without the script and that is successful to anyone outside the domain as well.

Any suggestions?

MailApp.sendEmail("testemail@gmail.com", "Subject", "Txt"); **- its lost**
MailApp.sendEmail("testemail@domen_on_workspace", "Subject", "Txt"); **- its OK**

Comment: Have you asked your admin about it?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I asked. Workspace' support does not know what is the reason.And I already found: for new Workspaces you need to use "GmMailApp.sendEmail(". Thank you!